# How to switch to main thread (if I use my own game loop) in .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, game-development

Given:

- Game loop is running on the main thread of console app.
- Game actions/events are fired on other threads.

Question:

- How can I switch/forward those actions/events to the main thread?

Next I will give my implementation. But I don't like it for several reasons:

- My custom TaskScheduler. I'm just afraid that I might write something wrong.
- No synchronization context.
- Game loop ticks every N milliseconds but it would be better if it reacted to new actions/events.

So, are there a better ways to do this?

```
class Program {


    private static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        var game = new Game();
        new Timer( i => game.ActionAsync().Wait(), null, 0, 3000 );
        new Timer( i => game.EventAsync().Wait(), null, 0, 3000 );
        game.Run();
    }


}
```

```
public class Game {

    private GameTaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get; } = new GameTaskScheduler();


    public Game() {
    }


    // Run game loop
    public void Run() {
        while (true) {
            TaskScheduler.Execute();

            // Game logic
            Console.WriteLine( "Update: {0:00}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId );
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
        }
    }


    // User action
    public async Task ActionAsync() {
        await SwitchToMainThread();
        Console.WriteLine( "Action: {0:00}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId );
    }
    // User event
    public async Task EventAsync() {
        await SwitchToMainThread();
        Console.WriteLine( "Event: {0:00}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId );
    }


    // Utils
    public AwaitExtensions.TaskSchedulerAwaitable SwitchToMainThread() {
        return TaskScheduler.SwitchTo();
    }


}
```

[Discussion about TaskScheduler](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/discussions/1057)

```
// todo: Can I do it without custom TaskScheduler?
internal class GameTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler {

    private ConcurrentQueue<Task> Tasks { get; } = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();
    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;

    public void Execute() {
        while (Tasks.TryDequeue( out var task )) {
            TryExecuteTask( task );
        }
    }
    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) {
        return false;
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task) {
        Tasks.Enqueue( task );
    }
    protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task) {
        return false;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task>? GetScheduledTasks() {
        return Tasks.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version with locks and ManualResetEvent allowing you to wait for a task.
It looks like it works, but I'm afraid there might be bugs in some rare cases. Can you tell me if I did it right?

[Discussion about TaskScheduler](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/discussions/1057)

```
public class Game {

    private GameTaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get; } = new GameTaskScheduler();


    public Game() {
    }


    // Run game loop
    public void Run() {
        while (true) {
            TaskScheduler.Wait();
            TaskScheduler.Execute();

            // Game logic
            Console.WriteLine( "Update: {0:00}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId );
        }
    }


    // User action
    public async Task ActionAsync() {
        await SwitchToMainThread(); // Switch to game thread
        Console.WriteLine( "Action: {0:00}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId );
    }
    // User event
    public async Task EventAsync() {
        await SwitchToMainThread(); // Switch to game thread
        Console.WriteLine( "Event: {0:00}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId );
    }


    // Utils
    public AwaitExtensions.TaskSchedulerAwaitable SwitchToMainThread() {
        return TaskScheduler.SwitchTo();
    }


}
```

```
// todo: Can I do it without custom TaskScheduler?
internal class GameTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler {

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;
    private Queue<Task> Tasks { get; } = new Queue<Task>();
    private ManualResetEvent Event { get; } = new ManualResetEvent( false );


    public void Wait() {
        Event.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Execute() {
        var tasks = default( Task[] );
        lock (Tasks) {
            tasks = Tasks.ToArray();
            Tasks.Clear();
            Event.Reset();
        }
        var exceptions = default( List<Exception> );
        foreach (var task in tasks) {
            try {
                TryExecuteTask( task );
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                exceptions ??= new List<Exception>();
                exceptions.Add( ex );
            }
        }
        if (exceptions != null && exceptions.Any()) {
            throw new AggregateException( exceptions );
        }
    }
    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) {
        return false;
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task) {
        lock (Tasks) {
            Tasks.Enqueue( task );
            Event.Set();
        }
    }
    protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task) {
        return false;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() {
        lock (Tasks) {
            return Tasks.ToArray();
        }
    }

}
```